# How to add time intelligence columns instead of years? For multiple measures

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a large number of measures displaying in rows. How would I go about adding MTD, YTD, CY, PY etc columns where I've currently got years displaying? Eg. do I need to create a MTD measure for each measure? And also, how would I go about adding it to the table?

Any tips or links to videos or blogs explaining in as much detail of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is the current table, and I'd like to replace the years with time intelligence columns]

Comment: You may want to start from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/powerplatform/power-bi?WT.mc_id=sitertzn_learntab_guidedlearning-card-powerbi  … and as examples for a “third party” sources: https://radacad.com/introduction-to-power-bi-what-is-power-bi … “fast track” about DAX: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/bi-sql-server/creating-calculated-columns-using-dax/ … your favorite search engine can provide you with further links as well. Good luck!

Comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculation-groups/